# I want to get coordinated, capture image onPasswordFailed() using DeviceAdminReceiver and send it via mail. i am stuck on image capturing

Tags: java, android

MyDeviceAdminReceiver.Java

```
package com.example.securitycapture;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver;
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;
import android.view.Surface;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Objects;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class MyDeviceAdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "MyDeviceAdminReceiver";
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
    private static final int IMAGE_QUALITY = 100;

    @Override
    public void onPasswordFailed(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPasswordFailed(context, intent);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((AppCompatActivity) context,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
            } else {
                captureImage(context);
            }
        } else {
            captureImage(context);
        }
    }

    private void captureImage(Context context) {
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            String cameraId = getBackCameraId(cameraManager);

            Size imageDimensions = getImageDimensions(cameraManager, cameraId);

            final ImageReader imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(
                    imageDimensions.getWidth(),
                    imageDimensions.getHeight(),
                    ImageFormat.JPEG,
                    1
            );

            List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<>(2);
            outputSurfaces.add(imageReader.getSurface());

            final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
                    try {
                        CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
                        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(imageReader.getSurface());
                        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

                        camera.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                                try {
                                    session.capture(captureRequestBuilder.build(), new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                                            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                                            imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(reader -> {
                                                Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                                                ByteBuffer buffer = Objects.requireNonNull(image).getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                                                byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                                                buffer.get(bytes);

                                                saveImage(context, bytes);

                                                image.close();
                                                camera.close();
                                            }, null);
                                        }
                                    }, null);
                                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Capture session configuration failed.");
                            }
                        }, null);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
                    camera.close();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice camera, int error) {
                    camera.close();
                }
            };

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                cameraManager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Camera permission not granted.");
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getBackCameraId(CameraManager cameraManager) throws CameraAccessException {
        for (String cameraId : cameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            int cameraOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);

            if (cameraOrientation == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK) {
                return cameraId;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Size getImageDimensions(CameraManager cameraManager, String cameraId) throws CameraAccessException {
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
        StreamConfigurationMap streamConfigurationMap = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        Size[] sizes = Objects.requireNonNull(streamConfigurationMap).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
        if (sizes != null && sizes.length > 0) {
            return sizes[0];
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void saveImage(Context context, byte[] imageBytes) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault());
        String currentDateAndTime = sdf.format(new Date());
        String fileName = "IMG_" + currentDateAndTime + ".jpg";

        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
            storageDir.mkdirs();
        }

        File imageFile = new File(storageDir, fileName);

        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile)) {
            outputStream.write(imageBytes);
            Log.d(TAG, "Image saved: " + imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SecurityCapture"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <!-- Add your services, activities, and providers here -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.securitycapture.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <receiver
            android:name=".MyDeviceAdminReceiver"
            android:description="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Deivce_admin.xml

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-policies>
        <limit-password />
        <watch-login />
        <disable-camera />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

I have shared all code. I am beginner in android development. I want to do this as a learning project.
I have tried multiple times but still unable to capture the image. What is wrong or is there any better solution to this?
Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Pls post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).